# importing .OSM to blender in 2.8

Tags: mesh, blender-osm

hello I was watching a tutorial on creating a city in Blender with the open street map website, but it seems that blender no longer has the importing .OSM addon.The tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4ySFm4ey9U&t=223s

Comment: You can get BlenderGIS at: https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS it's free

Comment: The blender-osm addon used in that video is free now. See my answer below for the details.

Answer (score 2):

Blender-osm addon is free now. Get it [here](https://gumroad.com/l/blender-osm).

All source code of the blender-osm addon is hosted on [Github](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm/tree/release). The addon documentation is also available at [Github](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm/wiki/Documentation).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i solved it like this:

reading:
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Generic_Distro

run:
apt install gcc g++ make cmake
apt install libx11-dev libxxf86vm-dev libxcursor-dev libxi-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libglew-dev
apt-get install python3-pip

later i downloaded blender-osm addon from official site:
https://prochitecture.gumroad.com/l/blender-osm

-make sure you have python installed correctly

[image]
before there was an error in the check phase
and I couldn't use the blender-osm add-on